# Log in screen requires mouse to show password field

Tags: 22.04, login-screen

The log in screen displays the user selection screen (only one user) and if I click the mouse, the password field is displayed and the keyboard works fine to enter the password.

However, I can't get from the user selection to the password field with just the keyboard. Enter, tab, escape etc. don't have any effect, it always requires intervention from the mouse.

- Ubuntu 22.04 fresh install (had the same issue on 18.04)
- Wayland
- Wired keyboard and bluetooth keyboard
- happens on both a fresh boot and a lock screen
- keyboard works fine in grub/bios before boot

Comment: Your question says you are using Ubuntu Core 22 and was using Ubuntu Core 18. The tag is for 22.04. Please correct the question with the correct info. Just saying 22 means it could be Ubuntu core 22 or Ubuntu 22.04 or Ubuntu 22.10 The only version of Ubuntu to use a single digit version number is Ubuntu Core.

Comment: done - it's 22.04